# Code First Approach Confusion in ASP.net MVC 4 EF5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been struggling for the last 10 or so hours trying to figure out and research the best way to achieve the relational code first database structure and class architecture that I'm after.

Unfortunately ASP and Google has defeated me so far!

I'll attach a UML diagram to better explain what I envision the system to do, I'm really just looking for an explanation on the approach I should be taking, where to keep certain functionality, if I need to create additional classes as View Models, Domain Models, How to link all of this into a Database Context, Do I need to create all the CRUD implementations myself? etc etc..

(I've used ArrayList as I'm from a Java background and know that best, I've been reading into ICollections and IEnumerables but can't decide which one to use?

[image: UML Diagram]

From my previous attempts I have so far tried:

- A single class implementing `DbContext` class which contains `DbSet`' for all of the `Room`, `Bunk` and `Booking` classes.
- A single domain class (is this right terminology?) for each "Entity" which stores the class data similar to the above, I've managed to generate databases from these with the help of `add-migrations` but the way it linked the `Room` and `Bunk` classes using an `ICollection` didn't seem to provide any way to access the bunks assosiated to a `Room` from the `Room.Bunks` ICollection when retrieving a bunk from the DB.
- I also had `RoomHelper` and `BunkHelper` classes which used `LINQ` statements to attempt to retrieve various data manually as well as the standard CRUD methods. This seemed to get confusing and made me think that I might be missing something that's auto generated for me?

It's a lot but I'm really struggling with this, any help is really appreciated :)

**As some people have requested below is the code I have created**

Bunk.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TestApplication.Models.Enums;

namespace TestApplication.Models
{
    public class Bunk
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 BunkId { get; set; }
        public BunkStatus BunkStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Room.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TestApplication.Models.Enums;

namespace TestApplication.Models
{
    public class Room
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 RoomId { get; set; }
        public String RoomName { get; set; }
        public Gender RoomGender { get; set; }
        public RoomStatus RoomStatus { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Bunk> Bunks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DatabaseContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApplication.Models
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Bunk> Bunks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This code has generated the below database structure, which doesn't allow me to access `Room.Bunks.All()` (as an example usage of the concept I'm misunderstanding)

[image: db preview]

Comment: Can you post the code where you were struggling to associate the `bunks` to a `room`?

Comment: Posting sample codes would be very helpful. Base upon what you've said, I think you have to create a virtual collection of Bunk in your Room Class. Also,  you have to include a bunkId in your room class. In your booking class, you can add a virtual collection of room. Because Room has access to Bunk, creating that virtual collection of room in Booking should give you access to Bunk also. Now, you can use a link query to check to see the bunk status.

Comment: You may have had trouble accessing Room.Bunks if you a) didn't tell entity framework to load the related entities when you performed your initial query using .Include and b) didn't make your ICollection<Bunk > property virtual so that the entity framework can load this collection on demand.

Comment: At a guess, the part where the concept breaks down is the missing part of your design. You want to research examples for Repository<T> and Unit of Work patter.  Otherwise you appear to be on the right path.

Comment: I've added the 3 main classes that I've started to implement, if anyone could have a look at those that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

These are the classes you would need:

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int RoomId { get; set; }

    public string RoomName { get; set; }

    public GenderEnum Gender { get; set; }

    public RoomStatusEnum RoomStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bunk> Bunks { get; set; }

    // convenience
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class Bunk
{
    [Key]
    public int BunkId { get; set; }

    public BunkStatusEnum BunkStatus { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Room")]
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }

    // convenience
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class Booking
{
    [Key]
    public int BookingId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Bunk")]
    public int BunkId { get; set; }
    public Bunk Bunk { get; set; }

    public int Duration { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Preferred_Room")]
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public Room Preferred_Room { get; set; }

    public Decimal Price { get; set; }

    public BookStatusEnum BookingStatus { get; set; }
}
```

The only thing I would caution you with is the foreign key to `Room` in `Booking`. If a `Bunk` can only belong to one `Room`, then you *already* have the chosen `Room` through `Bunk.Room`. By adding another foreign key to `Booking` for `Room`, you're creating a double-link that will make things like deletions arduous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can I ask why we store a RoomId as well as a Room object (and the same with Bunk), surely the RoomId can be accessed from within the room - or is this needed because when adding a migration it doesn't know how to use the Room.RoomId / Bunk.BunkId as the Foreign key?

Comment: I tried to add a migration for the code you supplied (with the exception that I commented out the attributes relating to UserProfiles, as that's a whole other question) and have received the below error message when trying to update to the database: `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Bookings_dbo.Rooms_RoomId' on table 'Bookings' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.` I've also done a paste bin of the code migration which can be found here: http://pastebin.com/ngXacrKV

Comment: That's due to the warning I gave you in my answer. Since `Room` is a foreign key to both `Booking` and `Bunk` and `Bunk` is also a foreign key on `Booking`. You're causing a bit a recursion in the delete cascade. The easiest and most appropriate solution is to remove `Room` from `Booking`. As I said, you can get to `Room` from `Bunk`. Otherwise, you'll have to specify the delete cascade for each entity manually to sort out the mess.

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand on my comment above because after now posting your code, it seems that you have indeed not made the navigation properties virtual.

You need to get a room object from the database, using a query of some sort. For example:

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext()){
    var room = context.Rooms.First();
}
```

In the above example, you will end up with a room object, but the entity framework will not automatically pull back all related entities (i.e. the Bunks).. in a lot of cases this would be overkill, in some cases it would be impossible. You need to specifically tell the entity framework which related entities you want it to bring back. e.g:

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext()){
    var room = context.Rooms.Include("Bunks").First();
}
```

In this example, the entity framework will load the Bunks as part of the query, and you will be able to access the bunks by using the syntax room.Bunks()

Finally, you can get the original example to work too if that's what you'd prefer. You would take advantage of something called Lazy loading, whereby the entity framework will only load related entities when you first access the navigation property (that is room.Bunks). This will require 2 calls to the database. First call to get the room, second to get the Bunks.

This will only work if you change your ICollection properties to be virtual:

```
public ICollection<Bunk> Bunks { get; set; }
```

needs to become

```
public virtual ICollection<Bunk> Bunks { get; set; }
```

This is because entity framework needs to know when you first access the Bunks collection. Entity framework does this by returning an object derived from the Room class, instead of your Room class, and it overrides the Bunks property with code which runs when you first access it. If this property is not virtual, then it can't do this, and therefore it won't work

Comment: Thanks! So In the example code above by Chris Pratt that would support the Lazy Loading method and being able to call bunks using the `var room = context.Rooms.Include("Bunks").First();` method?

Comment: That is correct. The Include syntax will work whether you make your properties virtual or not. It's just the Lazy loading feature which requires virtual properties.

Comment: So let's just make sure I've got this right. Lazy loading requires the `virtual` keyword and the `Include()` syntax to access the related table. Is that the best practice for doing this type of relationship?

Comment: Lazy loading requires the virtual keyword to work. It doesn't need the Include syntax, in fact using the Include syntax tells the entity framework to Eager load the entities (opposite of lazy loading). If you use neither the virtual keyword nor the Include syntax then you don't get related entities at all